# GAE/J logout but did not destroy session

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE1.6.3/Java, Federated login, i use the well-known

```
com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService.createLogoutURL(String destinationURL, String authDomain)
```

to create create logout url.

Using dev server, sign out after you sign in, when you try to sign in again, it will prompt with the login panel. Now input another user email, after logging in, i will see the same data with previous user.
After debug i found it is because the session is not destroyed after user logout, so another user login the system will recognized him as the previous user.

After delivering my app to appspot, when i log out then try to login, it did not take me to the login page and just go to my application directly. I think the correct behavior should be just like GMail. I think the root cause is same as dev server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks on logout they will log out of the App Engine app but not logged out of the federated provider. Its clearly mentioned in the following documentation:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid

For clearing the session in your application, give the logout url of the application and invalidate session using session.invalidate() and then redirect using com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService.createLogoutURL(String destinationURL, String authDomain)

Comment: I read the link and follow your instruction, and it works now, finally. Thank you.